# How to use selenium-wire to intercept traffic triggered from a html file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, intercept

I am using a simple html file that references a javascript file which internally makes a call to an https endpoint. And I need to intercept the request and response on the specific url programatically. I cannot invoke the URL directly. Usually, I would use a browser to load the html file and reference the network tab in the developer tools to intercept the call to the specific URL and that is manual. I need to mimic the same programatically.

I tried using the following -

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the Google home page
driver.get('file:///Users/myfolder/mypocfolder/mysimulator.html?param1=abcdefg')
# driver.get('https://example.com/xyz'); (This url gets called on loading the above url)
# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
print(len(driver.requests))
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

The above does not work for me. What other options can I try other than selenium? I am expecting the https://example.com/xyz will be called on loading my html (it happens in the browser).

Thank you

Comment: Is the [interceptor](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#intercepting-requests-and-responses) not working for you?
I use this to sign into a page, then monitor the request and response that this page automatically triggers. For me there's some JS code the makes a post request every 5 seconds or so and I want that, so I intercept the request and the response this way.